# Populate a column with forecasts of panel data using data.table in R

Tags: r, function, time-series, data.table, lag

I have a panel data with *"entity"* and *"year"*. I have a column *"x"* with values that i consider like time series. I want to create a new column *"xp"* where for each *"entity"* I give, for each *"year"*, the value obtained from the forecast of the previous 5 years. If there are less than 5 previous values available, xp=NA.

For the sake of generality, the forecast is the output of a function built in R from a couple of predefinite functions found in some packages like *"forecast"*. If it is easier with a specific function, let's use forecast(auto.arima(x.L5:x.L1),h=1).

For now, I use data.table in R because it is so much faster for all the other manipulations I make on my dataset.

However, what I want to do is not data.table 101 and I struggle with it. 
I would so much appreciate a bit of your time to help me on that.
Thanks.
Here is an extract of what i would like to do:

```
entity year   x    xp
1      1980   21   NA
1      1981   23   NA
1      1982   32   NA
1      1983   36   NA
1      1984   38   NA
1      1985   45   42.3 =f((21,23,32,36,38))
1      1986   50   48.6 =f((23,32,36,38,45))
2      1991    2   NA
2      1992    4   NA
2      1993    6   NA
2      1994    8   NA
2      1995   10   NA
2      1996   12   12.4 =f((2,4,6,8,10))
2      1997   14   13.9 =f((4,6,8,10,12))
...
```

As suggested by Eddi, I found a way using rollapply:

```
DT <- data.table(mydata)
DT <- DT[order(entity,year)]
DT[,xp:=rollapply(.SD$x,5,timeseries,align="right",fill=NA,by="entity"]
```

with:

```
timeseries <- function(x){
fit <- auto.arima(x)
value <- as.data.frame(forecast(fit,h=1))[1,1]
return(value)
}
```

For a sample of mydata, it works perfectly. However, when I use the whole dataset (150k lines), after some computing time, i have the following error message:

*Error in seq.default(start.at,NROW(data),by = by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument*

Where does it come from?
Can it come from the "5" parameter in rollapply and from some specifities of certain entities in the dataset (not enough data...)?

Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: check out `rollapply` in `zoo`

Comment: i do not manage to use the rollapply by entity.

Comment: maybe your data is not sorted correctly, try running `setkey(your_dt, entity, year)` before running your command; also you can add a `print` statement to see which group fails, e.g. `DT[, xp := {print(entity); rollapply(...)}, by = entity]` and debug your function for that group

Comment: Thanks. Comes from the number of year per entity. Solved.

Comment: You can self-answer your question with the exact solution that helped you, so others might learn as well.